# How to add a vertial scrollbar in Canvas?

Tags: java-me, canvas, scrollbar, lcdui

I am developing a Java ME application using [`Canvas`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html). The details displayed on the `Canvas` are plentiful, so I need to scroll down the screen to view the further details.

But how can I add a vertical scrollbar on a `Canvas`?

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you? let me know, so that you arrive at the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the scrollbar should be drawn inside the `paint` method. And you implement the `keyReleased` method when clicking the arrow of the scrollbar. To implement the `scrolling` I would prefer call `repaint();` and I will manage the `paint` method with `boolean` or some other type of private `variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your canvas as the source and the scroll bar as destination use the following formula to find the scroll bar position

```
Target point X co-ordinate: tX = taX + ((tW * (sX - saX)) / sW)

Target point Y co-ordinate: tY = taY - ((tH * (saY - sY)) / sH)

saX : Source axis start X coordinate

saY : Source axis start Y coordinate

sW : Souce Width

sH : Source Height

taX : Target axis start X coordinate

taY : Target axis start Y coordinate

tW : Target Width

tH : Target Height
```

The target height would be the height of the canvas. You must draw the scroll bar as the topmost element.